# How to position strip labels in facet_wrap like in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove the redundancy of strip labels when using `facet_wrap()` and faceting with two variables and both scales free.

For example, this `facet_wrap` version of the following graph

```
library(ggplot2)
dt <- txhousing[txhousing$year %in% 2000:2002 & txhousing$month %in% 1:3,]

ggplot(dt, aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(c("year", "month"), 
             labeller = "label_both", 
             scales = "free")
```

[image: facet_wrap_version]

should have the looks of this `facet_grid` version of it, where the strip labels are at the top and right edge of the graph (could be bottom and left edge as well).

```
ggplot(dt, aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(c("year", "month"), 
             labeller = "label_both", 
             scales = "free")
```

[image]

**Unfortunately, using `facet_grid` is not an option because, as far as I understand, it doesn't allow scales to be "completely free"** - see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1152) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685285/ggplot2-facet-grid-free-scales)

One attempt that I thought about would be to produce separate plots and then combine them:

```
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_gray()) 

p1 <- ggplot(dt[dt$year == 2000,], aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("month", scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "2000") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(dt[dt$year == 2001,], aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("month", scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "2001") + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

p3 <- ggplot(dt[dt$year == 2002,], aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("month", scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "2002") + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())

plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

**I am ok with the above hackish attempt, but I wonder if there is something in `facet_wrap` that could allow the desired output.** I feel that I miss something obvious about it and maybe my search for an answer didn't include the proper key words (I have the feeling that this question was addressed before).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not seem easy, but one way is to use grid graphics to insert panel strips from a facet_grid plot into one created as a facet_wrap.  Something like this:

First lets create two plots using facet_grid and facet_wrap.

```
dt <- txhousing[txhousing$year %in% 2000:2002 & txhousing$month %in% 1:3,]

g1 = ggplot(dt, aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(c("year", "month"), scales = "free") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())

g2 = ggplot(dt, aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(c("year", "month"), scales = "free")
```

Now we can fairly easily replace the top facet strips of `g1` with those from `g2`

```
library(grid)
library(gtable) 
gt1 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gt2 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2))
gt1$grobs[grep('strip-t.+1$', gt1$layout$name)] = gt2$grobs[grep('strip-t', gt2$layout$name)]
grid.draw(gt1)
```

[image]

Adding the right hand panel strips need us to first add a new column in the grid layout, then paste the relevant strip grobs into it:

```
gt.side1 = gtable_filter(gt2, 'strip-r-1')
gt.side2 = gtable_filter(gt2, 'strip-r-2')
gt.side3 = gtable_filter(gt2, 'strip-r-3')

gt1 = gtable_add_cols(gt1, widths=gt.side1$widths[1], pos = -1)
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, zeroGrob(), t = 1, l = ncol(gt1), b=nrow(gt1))

panel_id <- gt1$layout[grep('panel-.+1$', gt1$layout$name),]
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt.side1, t = panel_id$t[1], l = ncol(gt1))
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt.side2, t = panel_id$t[2], l = ncol(gt1))
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt.side3, t = panel_id$t[3], l = ncol(gt1))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @dww. Sorry for the delay. I like your two steps approach. I tried it out and works with a minor edit - I think you need to replace `gt.side1$widths[1]` with `gt1$widths[1]` when you edit `gt1` by adding a new column.

Comment: I didn't notice so far, but when you overwrite `gt1$grobs` with `gt2$grobs`, it overlays some of the top points of the upper panels. I think first a top row should be added `gt1 <- gtable_add_rows(gt1, heights = unit(0.5, 'cm'), pos = 2)` and then add the top facet labels with something like `gt1 <- gtable_add_grob(gt1, grobs = gt2$grobs[grep('strip-t', gt2$layout$name)], t = 2, l = gt1$layout[grep('strip-t.+1$', gt1$layout$name),]$l)`

Comment: Thanks @Valentin for catching that. The order of the code was wrong (using `gt.side1` before it was assigned). Fixed now.

Comment: I messed a little bit around. The posted solution did not work but as I removed the gt.side3 parts it worked. After that I tried to fix the top left corner which looks a bit off. You can bring the right facets onto the plot by playing with theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,0.65,0,0),"cm")) of gt1. If you want it perfect you can move the top facets upwards by playing with the heights of the finial gt1 object like so: gt1$heights[7] <- unit(0.6, "cm"). It does not have to be item number 7 in your case. Maybe this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Now it has become very easy with the help of `facet_grid2` function of `ggh4x` package. See my solution.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure you can do this by just using `facet_wrap`, so probably your attempt is the way to go. But IMO it needs an improvement.  Presently, you are missing actual `y-lab` (sales) and it kinda misguides what is plotted in `y- axis`

You could improve what you are doing by adding another plot title row by using `gtable` and `grid`.

```
p1 <- ggplot(dt[dt$year == 2000,], aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("month", scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(dt[dt$year == 2001,], aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("month", scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

p3 <- ggplot(dt[dt$year == 2002,], aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("month", scales = "free")
```

Note that the `labs` are removed from the above plots.

```
if ( !require(grid) )    { install.packages("grid");    library(grid) }
if ( !require(gtable ) )   { install.packages("gtable");    library(gtable) }

z1 <- ggplotGrob(p1) # Generate a ggplot2 plot grob
z1 <- gtable_add_rows(z1, unit(0.6, 'cm'), 2) # add new rows in specified position

z1 <- gtable_add_grob(z1,
                    list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = gray(0.7))),
                         textGrob("2000", gp = gpar(col = "black",cex=0.9))),
                    t=2, l=4, b=3, r=13, name = paste(runif(2))) #add grobs into the table
```

Note that in step 3, getting the exact values for `t (top extent)`, `l(left extent)`, `b (bottom extent)` and `r(right extent)` might need trial and error method

Now repeat the above steps for p2 and p3

```
z2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
z2 <- gtable_add_rows(z2, unit(0.6, 'cm'), 2) 

z2 <- gtable_add_grob(z2,
                      list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = gray(0.7))),
                           textGrob("2001", gp = gpar(col = "black",cex=0.9))),
                      t=2, l=4, b=3, r=13, name = paste(runif(2))) 

z3 <- ggplotGrob(p3) 
z3 <- gtable_add_rows(z3, unit(0.6, 'cm'), 2)

z3 <- gtable_add_grob(z3,
                      list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = gray(0.7))),
                           textGrob("2002", gp = gpar(col = "black",cex=0.9))),
                      t=2, l=4, b=3, r=13, name = paste(runif(2)))
```

finally, plotting

```
plot_grid(z1, z2, z3, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

You can also have the years indicated in the column like in `facet_grid` instead of row. In that case, you have to add a column by using `gtable_add_cols`. But make sure to (a) add the column at the correct position in step-2, and (b) get the correct values for `t`, `l`, `b` and `r` in step-3.

Comment: `plot_grid` seems to be deprecated, is there an updated alternative to this?

Comment: @elcortegano It is not deprecated, you should use `cowplot::plot_grid()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using `facet_grid2` function of `ggh4x` package like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

dt <- txhousing[txhousing$year %in% 2000:2002 & txhousing$month %in% 1:3,]

ggplot(dt, aes(median, sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid2(c("year", "month"), 
             labeller = "label_both", 
             scales = "free", independent = "all")
```

[image]