# R ggplot2: How can I name the y axis depending on the value of a variable with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'll give you an idea of the data and I think then it should be easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Repex:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
cat <- c("Others", "Others", "Population", "Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage")
logT <- c(2.7, 2.9, 1.5, 4.3, 3.7, 3.3)
m <- c(1.7, 1.9, 1.1, 4.8, 3.2, 3.5)
aggr <- c("median", "median", "geometric mean", "mean", "mean", "mean")
over.under <- c("overestimation", "overestimation", "underestimation", "underestimation", "underestimation", "underestimation")
data <- cbind(ID, cat, logT, m, aggr, over.under)
data <- data.frame(data)
data$ID <- as.numeric(data$ID)
data$logT<- as.numeric(data$logT)
data$m<- as.numeric(data$m)
```

Code:

```
Fig <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = logT, y = m, color = over.under)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ ID) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "log (True value)", limits=c(1, 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, limits=c(1, 7)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position='none')
Fig
```

I want to label the y axis of each graph with the value of `aggr`. So for ID 1 it should say median, for ID 2 geometric mean and ID 3 mean.

I tried multiple things:

```
mtext(data1$aggr, side = 2, cex=1) #or
ylab(data1$aggr) #or
strip.position = "left"
```

But it doesn't work.

I'm also trying to add the `cat` in the top left corner of the graph. So for ID 1 "Others", ID 2 "Population" and ID 3 "Percentage". I tried to work with `legend()` but I have not been able to solve the problem yet either.

Answer (score 9):

mtext is meant for `plot()`. ggplot is another plotting system so it will not work. Not many choices unfortunately, one way is to remove the xlab, and use the strip as a y-axis:

```
LAB =tapply(as.character(data$aggr),data$ID,unique)

Fig <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = logT, y = m, color = over.under)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "log (True value)", limits=c(1, 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, limits=c(1, 7)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position='none') +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free_y",strip.position = "left", 
  labeller = as_labeller(LAB ))  +
  ylab(NULL) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

The other way is to combine plots:

```
library(gridExtra) 

plts = by(data,data$ID,function(i){
ggplot(i,aes(x=logT,y=m,color=over.under)) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_x_continuous(name = "log (True value)", limits=c(1, 7)) +
scale_y_continuous(name = unique(i$agg), limits=c(1, 7)) +
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
theme_bw() + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("overestimation"="turquoise","underestimation"="orange"))+
theme(legend.position='none') 
})

grid.arrange(grobs=plts,ncol=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If we care about the `ID` facet labels, this gets a lot more complicated and is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706599/how-to-position-strip-labels-in-facet-wrap-like-in-facet-grid).

First, we need to make two copies of the plot, one with the renamed strips and one with the original.

Then we add the facet strips manually to the other.

```
library(gtable)
library(grid)
plot1 <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = logT, y = m, color = over.under)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free_y",strip.position = "left",  labeller = as_labeller(c(`1`="median",`2`="geometric mean",`3`="mean"))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "log (True value)", limits=c(1, 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, limits=c(1, 7)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(legend.position='none',strip.background = element_blank(),strip.placement = "outside")

plot2 <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = logT, y = m, color = over.under)) + 
  facet_grid(~ ID) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "log (True value)", limits=c(1, 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, limits=c(1, 7)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(legend.position='none')

gt1 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot1))
gt2 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot2))
strip1 <- gtable_filter(gt2, 'strip-t-1')
strip2 <- gtable_filter(gt2, 'strip-t-2')
strip3 <- gtable_filter(gt2, 'strip-t-3')
gt1 = gtable_add_rows(gt1, heights=strip1$heights[1], pos = 0)
panel_id <- gt1$layout[grep('panel-.+1$', gt1$layout$name),]
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, strip1, t = 1, l = panel_id$l[1])
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, strip2, t = 1, l = panel_id$l[2])
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, strip3, t = 1, l = panel_id$l[3])
gt1 = gtable_add_grob(gt1, zeroGrob(), t = 1, l = 1)
gt1 = gtable_add_rows(gt1, heights=gt2$heights[1], pos = 0)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt1)
```

[image]