# ggplot2 facets with different y axis per facet line: how to get the "best" from both facet_grid and facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

**Context:** I have a dataframe with a numeric column `Type` recorded for two categories (`conc` and `uptake` in the example below). With my real data, I need to make a facetted plot as presented below.

**Problem:** Setting `scales = "free_y"` does not "free" the y scale for facets of the same **line**, indeed, when values of the category `conc` are much bigger than the values of the category `uptake`, the latter is "crushed".

**Question:** is it possible to free the y axis scale for facets of the same line using `facet_grid()` or change facet-label from `facet_wrap()` to match those of `facet_grid()`?

**Trials and errors:** I have tried `facet_wrap()` but I did not acheived the neat layout of `facet_grid()` while the y-axis scale was good. Maybe there is a way to define `facet_wrap()` facet-labels but playing around with `switch` (*i.e.* `strip_position`) arguments has not been a success.

I am aware that some SO post are already looking for something similar (see [How to position strip labels in facet_wrap like in facet_grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52706599/10264278)) but maybe (I hope ^^) another, maybe "easier" solution came out since.

```r
library(magrittr) # for %>%
library(tidyr) # for pivot longer
library(ggplot2)
df <- CO2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("conc", "uptake"))
# nice facet labels but bad y-axis
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Type, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(Treatment ~ name, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

```r
# nice y-axis but bad facet labels
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Type, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(Treatment ~ name, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ggh4x::facet_grid2()` function has an `independent` argument that you can use to have free scales within rows and columns too. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.

```r
library(magrittr) # for %>%
library(tidyr) # for pivot longer
library(ggplot2)

df <- CO2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("conc", "uptake"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Type, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(Treatment ~ name, scales = "free_y", independent = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Neat solution! Many thanks :)

Comment: `ggh4x` is great!!!

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a similar issue and this solution partially worked for me. In my case, I'd like the columns to have their own independent scales but the rows within each column to have fixed scales. This is the case in the image above, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement this with `ggh4x`. Any suggestions @teunbrand?

Comment: @TarJae @Julian bump! I would also love to have a separate, fixed, kind of y scale in each `facet_grid` column. Is there an easy solution to that?