# Combine facet_grid stucture with facet_wrap axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have Data similar to this Example (with a larger value range).

```
Day <- rep(1:5, times=6) 
Fruit <- rep(c("Apple", "Banana", "Blueberry"), times = c(15,10,5)) 
Colour <- rep( c("Yellow","Red", "Green", "Yellow","Blue", "Purple"), each=5)
Values <-rep(c(3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8,9), times=2) 
SorS <- rep("Sweet", times=30) 
sweet <-data.frame(Day, Fruit, Colour, Values, SorS) 
SorS <- rep("Sour", times = 30) 
sour <- data.frame(Day, Fruit, Colour, Values, SorS) 
sour$Values <- sour$Values*10 
sour$Day <- sour$Day*10 
Data <- rbind(sweet, sour)
```

It would be nice to have single axis for each facet, as present using facet_wrap

```
ForPlot <-  ggplot(Data, aes(Day, Values), fill=Colour)

    ForPlot+
      geom_point(aes(fill=Colour))+
      ggtitle("Fruity Colours")+
      ylab("Values") + xlab("Day") +
      facet_wrap(SorS~Fruit,  scales= "free", ncol=3)
```

[image]

To simplify the understanding of what is displayed (and compared), it would be great to combine these diagrams(separate axis) with the table like labelling structure of facet_grid:

```
ForPlot <-  ggplot(Data, aes(Day, Values), fill=Colour)

ForPlot+
  geom_point(aes(fill=Colour))+
  ggtitle("Fruity Colours")+
  ylab("Values") + xlab("Day") +
  facet_rep_grid(SorS~Fruit,  scales= "free", switch="y")
```

[image]

I hope my problem is understandable. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position strip labels in facet_wrap like in facet_grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337468/combine-facet-grid-stucture-with-facet-wrap-axis#63337468) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257563/different-x-and-y-axis-scales-in-multifaceted-scatter-ggplot2).